# text too small to read (mobile design)

Tags: html, css

I have been coding a plain HTML and CSS website with no template.
One of the major pains has been trying to make my site mobile-friendly.

PAGE: https://www.gatewaysofhislight.com/characters/benaiah/

I used this code in the 'head' section:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3"
```

There is one stubborn alarm that keeps failing google's mobile-friendly test. It says the "text is too small to read" even though my CSS file calls for 18px Georgia text which should be more than large enough. I have tried bringing up this page on my phone and it reads just fine with no pinching or zooming required. Here is the CSS code for the body text

```
body {
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  word-spacing: .1em;
  font-family: Georgia, Times-new-roman, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(220,220,220);
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  line-height: 2.3em;}
```

Hopefully someone here can help suggest a line of code to add or alter to my page to make the googlebot happy, as google is now basing their pagerank more on mobile-friendliness.

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"
```

It'll work

Your code above, it makes everything looks smaller in mobile device because you used initial-scale=0.3. And when you use initial-scale=1 like I said, you should restyle something in your code to make your web look better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The 1.0 passed the mobile-friendly test but was a little too large and caused the column of text to be very narrow. I tried tweaking your line of code to 0.6 instead and now it looks good on mobile and passes the test also. Thank you for the help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use 0.6, but 1.0 is the exactly way that you should use. You can use 1.0 and learn to use responsive to make your web look better
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 2):

Steps to Avoid three errors (**Text too small to read** , **Clickable elements too close together** , **Content wider than screen**) in the Google Search Console:

1. Check whether the css is working or not, if its working then check the Your website in mobile phone. if its working perfect in mobile even its coming the problem in Google search console follow these steps...
2. Create a Robots.txt file in Public_HTML(C panel)
3. what ever the links tags or scripts tags or img tags you have used for your website copy that Urls and paste into the robots.txt file like this...

   User-agent: *
   Disallow:

   User-agent: *
   allow: https://Your_website/css/example_1.css
   allow: https://Your_website/css/example_2.css
   allow: https://your_website/js/js/example_1.js
   allow: https://your_website/js/js/example_2.js

**Note : Please wait for 24 hrs to 48 hrs then check in the google search console your errors will not available** :)